# Color picker with color shades in Gridview

Tags: android, gridview, color-picker

In one of my applications, i need to use/create a color picker in which color shades for selected colors must be shown in gird view and not as color gradient.

Currently I am using [this](https://github.com/brk3/android-color-picker) example for picking up color, but it shows color shades in gradient, my requirement is to show color shades in grid view.
Please guide for the same.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by showing in gridView ?

Comment: Do you want similar like this https://github.com/gabrielemariotti/colorpickercollection

Comment: means display shades for particular color like [this](http://www.ilikewallpaper.net/ipad-air-wallpapers/download/16694/Flip-Color-Grid-ipad-4-wallpaper-ilikewallpaper_com.jpg) and not like [this] (http://d241yswl6yg9sc.cloudfront.net/gradient2/top-new.jpg)

Comment: @GrlsHu Yes like this, but this example has specified several colors statically, I want the same for any color dynamically